# AsyncTask is restarting when i press back button

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have an activity with multiple AsyncTask's, but when i press back button, the Activity is reloaded and the AsyncTask's are executed again. what should i do  to Back to the previous activity and not  reload the activity and asynctask ? please help.

```
public class LugarActivity extends SherlockActivity {

CargarDatos cargarDatos;
CargarComentarios cargarComentarios;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_lugar); 

         cargarDatos = new CargarDatos();
         cargarCometarios = new CargarComentarios();

         loadData();
}

public void loadData(){
     cargarDatos.execute();

}

public void loadOtherData(){
     cargarComentarios.execute();
}


public class CargarDatos extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                // here download data
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String html) {         
             loadOtherData();           
            }

}


public class CargarComentarios extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                // here download data
            }

}



}
```

**FIXED!**

i fixed the problem with Singleton class:

```java
public class DataManager {

 private static DataManager instance = null;
 protected static boolean isShowingTheView = false;

 protected DataManager() {       }

 public static synchronized DataManager getInstance() {
         if (instance == null) {
                 instance = new DataManager();
         }
         return instance;
 }

}
```

in the activity i add this code:

```java
DataManager dataManager = new DataManager();
if(!dataManager.isShowingTheView){
        loadData();
        dataManager.isShowingTheView = true;

    }else{
        finish();
    }
```

and finally i override the onDestroy() method

```java
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    dataManager.isShowingTheView = false;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Had the same problem, I added a if to verify if I needed to launch loadData

Answer (score 0):

Remove `loadData()` from `onCreate` and call somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fragments

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

A fragment can stay in memory during a configuration change and therefore you can run your asynctask inside itself. You can then query the fragment for any state information you require from your tasks and update your Activity accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Activity` is destroyed before the other activity starts, using the back button will call `onCreate` again, instead of `onRestart` or `onResume`.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) for details.

As Kuffs already mentions, using `Fragment`s is the way to go.

Uglier solution, you could also set a shared preference holding a `boolean` once your `AsyncTask` is launched (or on its `onPostExecute`) so that it won't launch again after checking for that preference on your `Activity`'s `onCreate`.